# Error when I try to install Dlib with pip. macOS

Tags: python, macos, cmake, pip, dlib

Cant install Dlib with pip install Dlib, it gives me this error:

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting dlib
  Downloading dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2 MB 1.8 MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/tmp/pip-wheel-lj7iq51r
       cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/
  Complete output (69 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34)
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
  CMake Error at /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
    The C compiler

      "/usr/bin/cc"

    is not able to compile a simple test program.

    It fails with the following output:

      Change Dir: /tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

      Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_fe1fa/fast && xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
      Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
      See `man xcode-select` for more details.





    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/tools/python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-2gwrjrbi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/dlib
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/
    Complete output (71 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34)
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
    CMake Error at /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
      The C compiler

        "/usr/bin/cc"

      is not able to compile a simple test program.

      It fails with the following output:

        Change Dir: /tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

        Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_f5f8f/fast && xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
        Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
        See `man xcode-select` for more details.





      CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/tools/python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-2gwrjrbi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/dlib Check the logs for full command output.
```

Im on macOS Catalina 10.15.3.
I have Anaconda and cmake installed.
I'm pretty new to stack overflow.
I have multiple versions of python installed (I don't know if that's a problem) I mainly use 3.7.

I never seen these errors on the forums before.
I don't know what to do!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: "is not able to compile a simple test program" you did not have gcc compiler install on your system

Comment: The command `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` is written write in the error message.

Comment: @phd: Editing output messages is what is strongly discouraged on Stack Overflow. Instead, use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` for disabling syntax highlighting. I have already fixed given question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect your output. Console tells you specifically:

```
It fails with the following output:

        Change Dir: /tmp/pip-install-884s1u35/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

        Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_f5f8f/fast && xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
        Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
        See `man xcode-select` for more details.
```

CMake needs XCode Command Line Developer Tools to be able to build a project.

So open up *Terminal*, and run:

`sudo xcode-select --install`

Or, if you know you've installed it before, point to the Xcode with the tools installed:

`sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app`